# Stringify the <% tablename.item %>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a table of content similar to wikipedia's where it scrolls the page to a certain  when you click on a topic.

The problem is that I am using

```
<span class="mw-headline" id=<% pin.foodtype %>></span>
```

instead of

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="appetizers"></span>
```

`pin.foodtype` is from the table pin and foodtype is one of it's rows and it gives me exactly 'appetizers' but it doesn't register the id when I use it. It does work when I use the 2nd method but I want to do it with the first method.

Is there some kind of "stringify" that I can apply to it?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Would you reformulate? What is the method you're using, and what are you expecting/trying to do?

Comment: Go to a wikipedia article and click on a link in the TOC and it will scroll the page to a span. I want to do that in terms of ERB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use [`content_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) instead of mixing HTML and ERB:

```
<%= content_tag :span, '>', class: 'mw-headline', id: pin.foodtype %>
```

One of the benefits using this method is that is escapes the values correctly.

Comment: Thank you sir! Very cool! I like to add that you forgot a comma between ' and id though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
<span class="mw-headline" id="<%= pin.foodtype %>"></span>
```